# Error registering Avro schema: "string"

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

code to send  Avro message into the Kafka topic

```
 props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
            props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
            producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props); 

    public void send(List<String> results){
            TestCallback callback = new TestCallback();
            for (Object result : results) {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord(topic,result.toString());<==confused at this point
                producer.send(record,callback);

            }
            producer.close();
        }
```

send method contains List of records fetched from SQL query.

**Error**

```
2017-10-05 23:54:36 DEBUG RestService:118 - Sending POST with input {"schema":"\"string\""} to http://localhost:8081/subjects/my_topicq1-value/versions
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: "string"
```

At the end of the day, I wanted to fetch these records from the topic and by using Kafka-connect-hdfs to put into HDFS.

Can you please provide me some input so that I can proceed.
Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a bespoke Producer if you're pulling in SQL records -- can you just use Kafka Connect [JDBC Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html) to pull the data from your SQL query directly, and then Kafka Connect to land it to HDFS?